# Bokeh: how to make CDSView work with vectorized colors correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I'm definitely not the first person asking about it, but the previous questions have zero answers.

I'm using Bokeh MultiLine glyph with vectorized coloring. Everything is fine and on selection response is correct if CSD view is not specified (bottom graph). But an identical glyph on the top figure changes colors on selection. Moreover, tap selection does not work for the bottom figure if the top one has CDSView.

AFAIK people report similar behavior for other glyph types.

Is there any workaround to deal with this behavior? Did I miss some important CDSView parameters?
Thanks!

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, BooleanFilter, CDSView
from bokeh.layouts import column, gridplot
from bokeh.palettes import d3
import numpy as np

output_file('tst.html', mode="inline")
n = 4
t = np.linspace(0., 10., 80)
data = ColumnDataSource(dict(xx=[t for cnt in range(n)],
                             yy=[(10 + cnt/2)*np.sin(t) + 5*cnt*(-1)**cnt for cnt in range(n)],                             
                             clrs=d3['Category10'][4]))

test_filter = BooleanFilter([False, True, True, True])

view0 = CDSView(source=data, filters=[test_filter])
f1 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300, tools='tap,box_select,reset')
f2 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
f1.multi_line(xs='xx', ys='yy', source=data, color="clrs",
              view=view0,
              nonselection_alpha=0.4)

f2.multi_line(xs='xx', ys='yy', source=data, color="clrs",
              nonselection_alpha=0.4)
save(gridplot([[f1], [f2]]))
```

[Behavior on selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU9Tr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Bokeh 2.0.2 it is still an open issue: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9230#issuecomment-631291583

Also related: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8010

Comment: Thanks. After your update the issue was fixed by the next day. Do you know if a minor Bokeh release is going to happen any time soon?

Comment: Bokeh 2.1 should be out in early June